# how to extract an item from a level of factor if a single level has multiple items in t

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataframe - FD which is Factor with 6 levels as below

Levels: [1, 4, 5] [1,5] [1] [2, 4] [2] [3, 5]

but each level has more than one element in it. So how to extract/access elements/items from and individual level

```
sample<-read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)
df<-as.data.frame(sample)
df

v<-df$Nodes[]

w<-df$FirstDegree[]
for (i in v) {
  t<-c(1:5)
  if (df$FirstDegree[t][2]==i){
    print(1)
    }
  else {
    print(0)
    }
  }
```

#### I need to create a matrix with 1's and 0's where 1 represent whether the selected node value is present in FirstDegree, else zero. For which i am trying to access the items inside a level

Comment: Please put the output from `dput(df)` in your question!

Comment: @R_N does my post answer your question?

Comment: @R_N great! Consider marking my post as answered

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the factor to a character object and after that check whether the degree 1 to 5 is present in the string.

Assuming that this is your data

```
FirstDegree <- factor(c("[1, 4, 5]", "[1,5]", "[1]", "[2, 4]", "[2]", "[3, 5]"))
FirstDegree
Levels: [1, 4, 5] [1,5] [1] [2, 4] [2] [3, 5]
```

I would do

```
FirstDegree <- as.character(FirstDegree)

# sapply runs the code below for every possible degree 1 to 5
m <- sapply(1:5, function(degreenumber){
# we convert the number 1 to 5 to a character and see if this number
# is present in the vector FirstDegree. grepl returns TRUE or FALSE but since
# you asked for 1 or 0 we use as.numeric
as.numeric(grepl(as.character(degreenumber), FirstDegree))})
# the resulting matrix looks like this:
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    0    0
[6,]    0    0    1    0    1
```